# Use OpenGL dynamically draw shape (use epicycle and Fourier series)

Tags: c++, opengl

I want to render some shape use Fourier series and I have finished the render tools (arrow and pen) class. But the final output looks uncomfortable. My rendering idea is first set the arrows' positions, then use these position to render circles as handwriting painting shapes. After rotating a fix angle ,a position of arrow is set. This idea lends to the following output:

output effect:
[image]

Actually I want to render the line, and I don't know how to solve this. I use a FBO to store the handwriting, and render arrow in default FBO, the codes are following:

1. main.cpp

```
// include for create a window
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

// include for matrix calculation
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>
#include <glm/gtx/string_cast.hpp>

// include for creating arrow
#include "Arrow.h"

// include for creating pen 
#include "Pen.h"

// include for drawing circle
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height);
void processInput(GLFWwindow* window);
void renderBoard();

const int SCR_WIDTH = 800;
const int SCR_HEIGHT = 800;

int main()
{
    // initialize window glfw and configure
    // ------------------------------------
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
#ifdef __APPLE__
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE); // uncomment this statement to fix compilation on OS X
#endif
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, "LearnOpenGL", NULL, NULL);
    if (window == NULL) {
        std::cout << "Failed to create GLFW window" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, framebuffer_size_callback);
    glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_CURSOR, GLFW_CURSOR_DISABLED);

    if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress)) {
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLAD" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // Create drawing board FBO
    unsigned int boardFBO;
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &boardFBO);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, boardFBO);
    unsigned int boardColorBuffer;
    glGenTextures(1, &boardColorBuffer);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, boardColorBuffer);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, boardColorBuffer, 0);

    if (glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
        cout << "Board Color Buffer isn't complete\n" << endl;
    }
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

    // Create arrow
    Arrow arrow1(1.1), arrow2;

    // Create Pen
    Pen pen = Pen(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.004);
    pen.setOriginPosition(glm::vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0));

    // Create Sahder
    Shader arrowShader("arrow.vs", "arrow.fs");
    Shader boardShader("board.vs", "board.fs");

    boardShader.use();
    boardShader.setInt("boardColorBuffer", 0);
    bool isFirst = true;

    // render loop
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        // input
        processInput(window);
        glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        arrow1.rotateArrow(0.5f);
        arrow1.setPosition(glm::vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0));
        arrow2.rotateArrow(5.0f);
        arrow2.setPosition(arrow1.getHeadPosition());


        // render pen draw
        // glViewport(0, 0, SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT);
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, boardFBO);
        glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
        if (isFirst) {
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
            isFirst = false;
        }
        arrowShader.use();
        pen.setOriginPosition(arrow2.getHeadPosition());
        pen.drawPen(arrowShader);
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

        // glViewport(0, 0, SCR_WIDTH * 2, SCR_HEIGHT * 2);
        glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        boardShader.use();
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, boardColorBuffer);
        renderBoard();

        arrowShader.use();
        arrow1.drawArrow(arrowShader);
        arrow2.drawArrow(arrowShader);

        // render
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}

void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height) {
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}

void processInput(GLFWwindow* window) {
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_PRESS) {
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, true);
    }
}

unsigned int boardVAO = 0;
unsigned int boardVBO;
void renderBoard() {
    if (boardVAO == 0) {
        float boardVertices[] = {
            -1.0,  1.0, 0.0,   0.0, 1.0,    // up-left
            -1.0, -1.0, 0.0,   0.0, 0.0,    // down-left
            1.0,  1.0, 0.0,   1.0, 1.0,    // up-right
            1.0,  -1.0, 0.0,  1.0, 0.0     // down right
        };
        glGenVertexArrays(1, &boardVAO);
        glBindVertexArray(boardVAO);
        glGenBuffers(1, &boardVBO);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, boardVBO);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(boardVertices), boardVertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(float), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
        glBindVertexArray(0);
    }
    glBindVertexArray(boardVAO);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

2. Arrow.h

```
#ifndef Arrow_h
#define Arrow_h

#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <glad/glad.h>

// include for matrix operation
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>

#include "Shader.h"

class Arrow {
public:
    Arrow(float scale = 1.0, glm::vec3 position = glm::vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)) {
        scale = scale;
        float arrowVertices[] = {
            // rectangle
            -0.001, 0.0,  0.0,      // bottom-left
            -0.001, 0.11, 0.0,      // up-left
            0.001, 0.0,  0.0,      // bottom-right
            0.001, 0.11, 0.0,      // up-right
                                   // triangle
                                   0.0,  0.15,  0.0,      // up
                                   -0.01, 0.11,  0.0,      // bottom-left
                                   0.01, 0.11,  0.0       // bottom-right
        };
        int arrowIndices[] = {
            0, 1, 2,
            2, 1, 3,
            4, 5, 6
        };
        arrowVertices[4] *= scale;
        arrowVertices[10] *= scale;
        arrowVertices[13] *= scale;
        arrowVertices[16] *= scale;
        arrowVertices[19] *= scale;

        headPos = initHeadPos = glm::vec3(0.0, arrowVertices[13], 0.0);
        tailPos = initTailPos = glm::vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

        rotateOffsetModel = glm::mat4(1.0);
        positionOffset = glm::mat4(1.0);
        positionOffset = glm::translate(positionOffset, position);

        glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
        glBindVertexArray(VAO);

        glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(arrowVertices), arrowVertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        glGenBuffers(1, &EBO);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
        glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(arrowIndices), arrowIndices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glBindVertexArray(0);


    }

    // draw arrow
    void drawArrow(Shader shader) {
        shader.use();
        // alert arrow position
        shader.setMat4("model", positionOffset * rotateOffsetModel);

        glBindVertexArray(VAO);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 9, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, (void*)0);
        glBindVertexArray(0);
    }

    // rotate arrow in local coordinate
    void rotateArrow(float degree, glm::vec3 axis = glm::vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0)) {
        rotateOffsetModel = glm::rotate(rotateOffsetModel, glm::radians(degree), axis);     // get rotate matrix
        headPos = glm::vec3(rotateOffsetModel * glm::vec4(initHeadPos, 1.0));
        tailPos = glm::vec3(rotateOffsetModel * glm::vec4(initTailPos, 1.0));
    }

    // set arrow's position
    void setPosition(glm::vec3 Position) {
        positionOffset = glm::mat4(1.0);
        positionOffset = glm::translate(positionOffset, Position);
        headPos = glm::vec3(positionOffset * rotateOffsetModel * glm::vec4(initHeadPos, 1.0));
        tailPos = glm::vec3(positionOffset * rotateOffsetModel * glm::vec4(initTailPos, 1.0));
    }

    // alert head and tail info
    void alertHeadTailPosition(glm::mat4 alertModel) {
        headPos = glm::vec3(alertModel * glm::vec4(initHeadPos, 1.0));
        tailPos = glm::vec3(alertModel * glm::vec4(initTailPos, 1.0));
    }

    // get head ( the up coordinate of triangle ) coordinate
    glm::vec3 getHeadPosition() {
        return headPos;
    }

    // get tail ( the middle coordinate of triangle's bottom ) coordinate
    glm::vec3 getTailPosition() {
        return tailPos;
    }
private:
    unsigned int VAO, VBO, EBO;
    glm::mat4 rotateOffsetModel, positionOffset;
    glm::vec3 headPos, tailPos;
    glm::vec3 initHeadPos, initTailPos;  // I find that the offset set will add if I always use one variable
    GLfloat Scale;
};

#endif /* Arrow_h */
```

3. Pen

```
// This class is used to create a pen which is used to draw the graph

#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "Shader.h"
#include <vector>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

#ifndef Pen_h
#define Pen_h
class Pen {
public:
    Pen(GLfloat xPos, GLfloat yPos, GLfloat zPos, GLfloat Radius)
        : originPosition(glm::vec3(xPos, yPos, zPos)), radius(Radius), edges(360) {
        configurePen();
    }

    Pen(glm::vec3 penPosition, GLfloat Radius)
        : originPosition(penPosition), radius(Radius), edges(360) {
        configurePen();
    }

    void configurePen() {

        allPenVertices.push_back(originPosition);
        GLfloat doublePi = 2.0 * M_PI;
        for (int i = 1; i < edges + 2; i++) {
            float x, y;
            x = originPosition.x + cos((float)i / edges * doublePi) * radius;
            y = originPosition.y + sin((float)i / edges * doublePi) * radius;
            allPenVertices.push_back(glm::vec3(x, y, 0.0));
        }
        glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
        glBindVertexArray(VAO);
        glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, allPenVertices.size() * 3 * sizeof(float), &allPenVertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glBindVertexArray(0);
    }

    void drawPen(Shader shader) {
        shader.use();
        glBindVertexArray(VAO);
        shader.setMat4("model", offsetModel);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, allPenVertices.size());
    }

    void setOriginPosition(glm::vec3 Position) {
        offsetModel = glm::mat4(1.0);
        offsetModel = glm::translate(offsetModel, glm::vec3(Position));
    }

private:
    GLfloat radius;
    glm::vec3 originPosition;
    GLint edges, numberOfVertices;
    vector<glm::vec3> allPenVertices;
    unsigned int VAO, VBO;
    glm::mat4 offsetModel;
};

#endif /* Pen_h */
```

Should I change my rendering idea? Or should I use a algorithm to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [...] it can't let them connect with each other [...]

Of course. You draw 1 dot per frame and the process runs to fast to generate "connected" dots.

You've to draw more than 1 dot per frame. e.g.:

```cpp
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, boardFBO);
if (isFirst) {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    isFirst = false;
}

arrowShader.use();
const int perFrame = 5;
for (int i = 0; i < perFrame; ++i) {
    arrow1.rotateArrow( 0.5f / perFrame );
    arrow1.setPosition( glm::vec3( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 ) );
    arrow2.rotateArrow( 5.0f / perFrame );
    arrow2.setPosition( arrow1.getHeadPosition() );

    pen.setOriginPosition( arrow2.getHeadPosition() );
    pen.drawPen( arrowShader );
}

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

[image]

---

I recommend to enable [Multisample anti-aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multisample_anti-aliasing).

Define the number samples per pixel, before the GLFW window is created ([`GLFW_SAMPLES`](https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__window.html#ga2cdf86fdcb7722fb8829c4e201607535)).e.g.:

```cpp
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 8);
```

Enable [`GL_MULTISAMPLE`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glEnable.xhtml) (this state by default is enabled):

```cpp
glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE);
```

---

Since you use a framebuffer you can [Multisample Render Target](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Multisampling#Allocating_a_Multisample_Render_Target) framebuffer to improve the result.

Set up the framebuffer and attach a `GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE` sampler to the color buffer:

```cpp
unsigned int boardColorBuffer;
glGenTextures(1, &boardColorBuffer);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, boardColorBuffer);
glTexImage2DMultisample(GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, 8, GL_RGB, SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, false);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

unsigned int boardFBO;
glGenFramebuffers(1, &boardFBO);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, boardFBO);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,
                       GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, boardColorBuffer, 0);

if (glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
    cout << "Board Color Buffer isn't complete\n" << endl;
}
```

Note, the texture, has to be bound to the target `GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE`:

```cpp
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, boardColorBuffer);
```

Interpolate the samples in the fragment shader. e.g.:

```c
in vec2 v_uv;
uniform sampler2DMS boardColorBuffer;

void main()
{
    const int samples = 8;

    vec2 size = textureSize(boardColorBuffer);
    vec4 color = vec4(0.0);
    for (int i=0; i<samples; ++i)
        color += texelFetch(boardColorBuffer, ivec2(v_uv*size), i);
    color /= float(samples);  

    // ...
}
```

In this case you should enable blending, with a blend equation of `dest * 1 + source * 1`. Note, since the multisampled fragments are interpolated, the color of the fragments a the border of the circle may not be completely "white". With blending you can avoid that such a fragment overrides a completely "white" fragment. e.g.:

```cpp
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, boardFBO);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE);
glBlendEquation(GL_FUNC_ADD);  

// draw pen respectively the pen-loop
// [...]

glDisable(GL_BLEND);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

Comment: I think It's just help a little but it can't solve this issue. After using multisample, I only get a smooth edge of those little circle, it can't let them connect with each other.

Comment: I am sorry I haven't elaborated clearly, my English is poor. And slowing down the rendering process is right. But it will be too slow in some situations . Is there another methods that can render a shape in acceptable rate? Thank you!

Comment: @Outo put your "dots" (vertices) in a vertex buffer and draw them all at once. Executing one draw call per vertex will be ridiculously slow. If you know the entire shape in advance, just draw the whole thing, but color everything of the arrow's position black (or totally transparent).

Comment: @Rabbid76 I'm sorry I haven't noticed the code. Thank you very much! I will try it tomorrow, it's midnight in my country. Your answer is helpful, thank you!

Comment: @3Dave Thanks for your reply. But In fact, I want to dynamically show the process of drawing shapes through Fourier series, instead of directly presenting the results of the drawing.

Comment: @Outro I understand that. If you pre-calculate all of your points and throw them into a vertex buffer, you can specify what portion of the buffer you want to draw in your glDraw call. You don't actually have to plot each point individually, and you don't have to draw the entire buffer.

Comment: @3Dave Oh!  That is really a good idea.  I am sorry that I misunderstood what you meant before, I will try it tomorrow, thank you very much for your advice!

Comment: @Outro look at your `glDraw` calls. Every draw call takes a parameter telling the runtime how many vertices to draw. Anything beyond that in the buffer is ignored.

Comment: @3Dave Thank you, I get it.